# implementing php's file_get_contents() in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, filereader

I am trying to input a file and get the same output as php's file_get_contents() but doing so in javascript. My javascript code is below:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", "http://localhost:3000/line.png", true );

xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function( e ) {

    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    console.log(arrayBufferView);
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/png" } );

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
            var blobStr = reader.result;
            console.log(blobStr);
    }
    reader.readAsText(blob, "iso-8859-1");

};
xhr.send();
```

When I use the above code I get what appears to be the exact same output as php's file_get_contents(). However it ends up being different output because when I md5 each string, I get different results. My example image is below:

[image]

Looking at the javascript string outputted in a div, I see this:
[image]

Looking at the php string outputted in a div, I see this:
[image]

As you can see, both look the same, except for maybe some formatting differences? Would this be the cause of my issues? How would I force the javascript version to have the same output as the php version?

Comment: If you want the "text" version, why not use `xhr.responseType = "text";` (the default) and simply retrieve `xhr.responseText`? Also, when looking at the content from PHP's output, you should probably look at the page source rather than the echo'd value on the webpage itself.

Comment: When I do that I get output that has question marks instead of some of the weird symbols. More importantly it doesn't have the same md5 as the php one. My main goal is for the strings to be exactly the same. Also what do you mean by look at the page source? I usually just echo when debugging but I'd love to know another way.

Comment: I mean CTRL+U on the browser and look at the echoed string there rather than on the rendered page itself.

Comment: Ah I see now. Helpful when analyzing, but I still need the strings to be the exact same when I end up hashing them. The php one is the working one because it matches the md5 I need, it's the javascript one that I need to fix to match the php one. Any ideas?